# Find the number of ways to select 2n balls from n identical blue balls, n identical red balls and n identical white balls, where n $\in$ $\mathbb N$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, multisets

Q: Find the number of ways to select 2n balls from n identical blue balls, n identical red balls and n identical white balls, where n $\in$ $\mathbb N$.

My working:

$(x+x^2+x^3+...)^3$

$=x^3(1+x+x^2+...)^3$

$= x^3 \sum_{r=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix} {r+3-1}\\{r}\end{pmatrix}x^r$

$= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix} {r+2}\\{r}\end{pmatrix}x^{3+r}$

Hence the number of ways is $\begin{pmatrix} {2n-1}\\{2n-3}\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix} {2n-1}\\{2}\end{pmatrix}$.

However, the actual answer is $\begin{pmatrix} {2n+2}\\{2}\end{pmatrix}$$-3$$\begin{pmatrix} {n+1}\\{2}\end{pmatrix}$. Did i go wrong somewhere in my proof? Or is it some conceptual understanding gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You admit that your answer is wrong.  Without seeing how you got there, we cannot find the error.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((2n-1)+choose+2)-((2n%2B2)+choose+2)%2B3((n%2B1)+choose+2)) says even the leading therm is wrong.

Comment: Hold on my bad. Making the edits now.

Comment: Alright its done! Sorry for the missing information!

Comment: @Stoner So, the question is why do you think that $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)^3$ has anything to do with this problem.  For one thing, $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)^3$ would imply that you have three *unlimited pools* of balls from which you take **at least one** from each.  You are certainly allowed to take zero blue balls if you so choose.  Another problem with this is that in your actual problem, you are limited to taking **at most $n$** of a specific color.  In reality, the generating function would be $(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)^3$ and you would be looking for the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the expansion.

Comment: Your answer seems to count the number of ways in which you can have $2n$ balls formed from identical white balls, identical blue balls, and identical red balls such that there is at least one of each color (but no upper limit).  To answer the correct problem, it is easier to approach via inclusion-exclusion in this case, which is where the correct answer in its given format comes from.  Apply inclusion-exclusion based on which of the upperbound conditions is violated noting that you cannot simultaneously violate more than one upperbound condition.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your clear and concise explanation! I realized the flaw in my reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is same as the number of solutions to $$x+y+z = 2n$$ where $0 \leq x, y, z \leq n$. Thus we need the coefficient of $t^{2n}$ in 
\begin{align*}
(1+t+t^2+ \cdots +t^n)^3 &= \left(\frac{1-t^{(n+1)}}{1-t}\right)^3\\
&=(1-3t^{(n+1)}+3t^{2(n+1)}-t^{3(n+1)})\left(1+\binom{3}{1}t + \binom{4}{2}t^2+ \cdots +\binom{3+k}{k+1}t^{k+1} + \cdots \right)
\end{align*}
Thus the required coefficient is 
$$\binom{2n+2}{2n} - 3 \binom{n+1}{n-1} = \binom{2n+2}{2} - 3 \binom{n+1}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easiest to count this directly, without any fancy tricks.  We actually end up with a simpler formula: $$\binom{n+2}{2}$$ or, equivalently, $$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$ (which is equal to the longer formula in @Muralidharan's answer).

Here's how it works:

The number $r$ of red balls is in the range from $0$ to $n,$ and the number $b$ of blue balls is also in the range from $0$ to $n.$

Given values for $r$ and $b,$ there's at most one possible value for the number of white balls: $w = 2n-r-b.$  But this potential number of white balls also has to be in the range from $0$ to $n.$  If $2n-r-b$ is in the range from $0$ to $n,$ then $\langle r, b, 2n-r-b\rangle$ is a triple we have to count.  If $2n-r-b$ is not in that range, then we should skip that triple and not count it.

Since each ordered pair $\langle r, b\rangle$ has at most one corresponding $w,$ this is the same as counting the number of ordered pairs $\langle r, b\rangle$ such that $0 \le r \le n, 0 \le b \le n,$ and $0 \le 2n-r-b \le n.$

So our count is as follows, using the notation $\#X$ for the cardinality of a set $X\!\!:$

\begin{align}
&\#\lbrace \langle r, b\rangle \mid 0 \le r \le n \;\land\; 0 \le b \le n \;\land\; 0 \le 2n-r-b \le n\rbrace
\\= &\#\lbrace \langle r, b\rangle \mid 0 \le r \le n \;\land\; 0 \le b \le n \;\land\; r + b \le 2n \;\land\; n \le r+b\rbrace
\\= &\#\lbrace \langle r, b\rangle \mid 0 \le r \le n \;\land\; 0 \le b \le n \;\land\; n-r \le b \le 2n-r\rbrace
\\= &\#\lbrace \langle r, b\rangle \mid 0 \le r \le n \;\land\; \max(0,n-r) \le b \le \min(n,2n-r)\rbrace.
\end{align}

For any $r \le n,$ we have $\max(0,n-r)=n-r$ and $\min(n,2n-r)=n,$ so the count above equals
\begin{align}
&\#\lbrace \langle r, b\rangle \mid 0 \le r \le n \;\land\; n-r \le b \le n\rbrace.
\end{align}

You can see that for each value of $r$ from $0$ to $n,$ we have $r+1$ possible values of $b$, namely $n-0, n-1, n-2, \dots, n-r.$

It follows that the total count equals

\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^n (r+1) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k
\\&= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2},
\end{align}

and this equals $$\binom{n+2}{2}$$ if you want to phrase the answer as a binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are selecting $2n$ balls from a total of $3n$ balls,

we can count how many ways we can choose the $n$ balls we are leaving out.

This is the number of solutions in nonnegative integers to $a+b+c=n$,

which is given by $\color{blue}{\dbinom{n+2}{2}}$.

---

Alternate solution:

We want to find the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=2n$ where $0\le x_i\le n$ for each $i$.

If S is the set of all solutions in nonnegative integers and if $A_i$ is the set of solutions with $x_i>n$,

we have $\big|\overline{A_1}\cap\overline{A_2}\cap\overline{A_3}\big|=\big|S\big|-\big|A_1\big|-\big|A_2\big|-\big|A_3\big|=\color{blue}{\dbinom{2n+2}{2}-3\dbinom{n+1}{2}}$